# Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace Photon

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I can not get into the Eclipse Marketplace.
I live in Korea and have access to wifi environment.
Wi-Fi status is best.
I searched Google for the same situation, but I could only see one massage like myself.
However, the article was written in the Eclipse Forum and I was not able to access the Eclipse Forum.
I also could not get into the Marketplace page on the Eclipse homepage.
Most of the errors I see are Connection Errors, but they are different from my error messages.
Below is my error message and my version is as follows.
[Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)]
[macOS Mojave ver. 10.14 (18A391)]

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Resource not found: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Cannot complete request to http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
Resource not found: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? If so go to preferences and search for proxy and enter your proxy server value, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the marketplace is unavailable.

Error | Drupal: "The website encountered an unexpected error."
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/